# JS TileMap iOS 8 and swift, incomprehensible archive?

Tags: objective-c, xml, swift, game-development, jstilemap

I've bridged JS TileMap for my spritekit game.  I've put a tmx file in my project and I'm trying to init a JSTileMap object

```
let map = JSTileMap(fileNamed: "level 1-1.tmx")
```

i get this error

2014-11-15 17:43:03.428 MyGame[5726:1901295] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSKeyedUnarchiver initForReadingWithData:]: incomprehensible archive (0x3c, 0x3f, 0x78, 0x6d, 0x6c, 0x20, 0x76, 0x65)'
*** First throw call stack:
(

Could it be that it's not finding the file?   I noticed if i change the filename to something nonexistent i get the same error..

Here is the contents of my tmx file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<map version="1.0" orientation="orthogonal" width="1000" height="800" tilewidth="1" tileheight="1">
 <tileset firstgid="1" name="enemies" tilewidth="80" tileheight="75">
  <tile id="0">
   <properties>
    <property name="name" value="EnemyA"/>
   </properties>
   <image width="66" height="75" source="../Atlases/iPhone/enemyA.atlas/enemy@2x.png"/>
  </tile>
  <tile id="1">
   <image width="65" height="67" source="../Atlases/iPhone/enemyB.atlas/enemy@2x.png"/>
  </tile>
  <tile id="2">
   <properties>
    <property name="name" value="EnemyC"/>
   </properties>
   <image width="60" height="60" source="../Atlases/iPhone/enemyC.atlas/enemy@2x.png"/>
  </tile>
  <tile id="3">
   <image width="61" height="65" source="../Atlases/iPhone/enemyD.atlas/enemy@2x.png"/>
  </tile>
  <tile id="4">
   <image width="74" height="58" source="../Atlases/iPhone/enemyE.atlas/enemy@2x.png"/>
  </tile>
  <tile id="5">
   <properties>
    <property name="name" value="EnemyF"/>
   </properties>
   <image width="80" height="73" source="../Atlases/iPhone/enemyF.atlas/enemy@2x.png"/>
  </tile>
 </tileset>
 <objectgroup color="#000000" name="Object Layer 1">
  <object name="EnemyA" type="enemy" gid="1" x="137" y="489"/>
  <object name="EnemyC" type="enemy" gid="6" x="468" y="454"/>
  <object name="EnemyB" type="enemy" gid="3" x="310" y="321"/>
 </objectgroup>
</map>
```

i've tried editing it down to just  and it still throws that error.  I'm making sure to include libz.dylib

what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using the wrong init method

it should be

```
let map = JSTileMap(named: "level 1-1.tmx")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove @2 from your image files source.. Then run it again. I think you cannot use @2 in tiled. Also remove spaces from you tmx name.